# Using variant + reference_wrapper + unique_ptr to express idea of (non)owning resource

Tags: c++, c++17

if I need to express such an idea:
there is a scene node (with a transformation) that can point to (*do not own*) geometry (mesh for example),
but sometimes it is very convenient for the node *to own* the geometry.
Is it OK to express this idea in this way? if not - could you give some thoughts on how to express this idea?

```
struct Node
{
    variant<reference_wrapper<SceneObject>, unique_ptr<SceneObject>> sceneObject{nullptr};
};

Node node1;
node1.sceneObject = make_unique<Mesh>(); // node is responsible for the life of the mesh

Node node2;
node2.sceneObject = sceneObjectDatabase.getResource("myMesh"); //the node does not own the mesh, but simply references it

Node node3;
node3.sceneObject = nullptr; // doesn't own any geometry
```

Comment: Ain't that a bit too many C++ tags?

Comment: Maybe a `std::shared_ptr` is what you are looking for, I guess.

Comment: Doesn't look too convenient to me. I'd explore a unique_ptr with a custom deleter. A unique_ptr with a no-op deleter is similar to a non-owning pointer.

Comment: @n.m. good point, but I think in this case user who looks at the class will  think that Node owns the resource.

Comment: You can typedef your custom unique_ptr to something like optionally_owning_ptr.

Comment: @n.m. thx. I'll consider this one.

Comment: why not just have the variant store the object directly, rather than indirectly through std::unique_ptr?

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a variant here. You don't have different types, you have one type - but just have a property of that type. So you could just write a maybe-owning type, that's basically a `T*` and a `bool`:

```
template <typename T>
class maybe_owning_ptr {
    T* ptr_;
    bool owns_;

public:
    maybe_owning_ptr() : ptr_(nullptr), owns_(false) { }
    maybe_owning_ptr(T* p, bool owns) : ptr_(p), owns_(owns) { }
    ~maybe_owning_ptr() {
        if (owns_) delete ptr_;
    }

    maybe_owning_ptr(maybe_owning_ptr&& rhs) noexcept
        : ptr_(std::exchange(rhs.ptr_, nullptr))
        , owns_(std::exchange(rhs.owns_, false))
    { }

    maybe_owning_ptr& operator=(maybe_owning_ptr&& rhs) noexcept
    {
        T* p = std::exchange(rhs.ptr_, nullptr);
        bool o = std::exchange(rhs.owns_, false);

        if (owns_) delete ptr_;
        ptr_ = p;
        owns_ = o;
        return *this;
    }

    // accessors here... get(), operator*, operator->(), etc.
};
```

Note that we can't have a copy constructor - because we wouldn't know what to do in the scenario where we do have ownership.

Always wanted to use [`std::exchange()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) for something...

Comment: Yeah, `std::exchange` is neat :)

Comment: For the copy constructor, If we do own then can't we just call the copy constructor for the underlying type? Yes, we may need to SFINAE that out if the underlying type doesn't have a copy constructor.

Comment: I like std::variant because it eliminates the need to implement these special member functions. It also uses value semantics and doesn't force you to use the heap.

Comment: But what if one needs a container of `maybe_owning_ptr`s (preferably a `std::array`) that have different underlying types? `std::variant` still seems like a good solution to prevent the template-explosion that `std::tuple` incurs.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t like the `variant` In your particular example, i.e. in a simple struct with direct access to the members. Although it gives you the flexibility regarding ownership, that flexibility bleeds into each usage of `Node::sceneObject`.

The variant is an implementation detail of your special ownership semantics. It should be decoupled from the usage of `sceneObject` because ownership is not the caller’s concern. However with the `variant` solution it’s tightly coupled because the caller has to do different things for owning and non-owning `sceneObject`s.

I like the idea of @n.m. of using a `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter. It gives you both the ownership flexibility and a consistent way of accessing `sceneObject`. Add a `make_owning_sceneObject()` and a `make_non_owning_sceneObject()` function and you have a nice and simple API.
Also that solution seems to have the least potential for performance penalties. Access is always a simple indirection through a pointer, no `variant` machinery at all. Of course, the usual caveats about unmeasured performance speculations apply.